# i'm completely new to JavaScript and i'm really confused about importing modules

Tags: javascript

now i saw this code in a video and I don’t know why when I remove the "." an error shows up, so what does it mean?

```
     import backpack from "./backpack.js";
    
    const markup = (backpack) => {
      return `
      <div>
        <h3>${backpack.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Volume: ${backpack.volume}</li>
          <li>Color: ${backpack.color}</li>
          <li>Number of pockets: ${backpack.pocketNum}</li>
          <li>Strap lengths: L: ${backpack.strapLength.left}, R: ${
        backpack.strapLength.right
      } </li>
          <li>Top lid: ${backpack.lidOpen ? "Open" : "Closed"}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    `;
    };
    
    const main = document.createElement("main");
    main.innerHTML = markup(backpack);
    document.body.appendChild(main);
    export default backpack;
```

Comment: There are 14 dots in your script, which one are you talking about? Also, include the error you're talking about.

Comment: Are you referring to the "." in the import statement?

Comment: _"an error shows up"_ What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import backpack from "./backpack.js";`

The code shown above is doing a relative import to a file by following the path your provide it. Beginning the path with `./` says "Start in the same folder as this file".

This is different to doing `import backpack from "backpack"` which doesn't use a file path and instead is looking for a module available in the browser. Therefore the JS runtime will search through the available modules and find the appropriate one, in this case `backpack`.

If you want a lot more information you can see MDN, though it might be too much information too fast. Good luck!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with node.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, I'll update my answer to be more generic to module syntax